# Passing a newcommand with one argument to another newcommand

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I am wondering how to define a new command `A` with another new command `B` (which has one argument `x`) as the argument of `A`.

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\ket[1][usedefault, addprefix=\global, 1=1]{|#1>}
\newcommand\hc[1][usedefault, addprefix=\global, 1=2]{Hc(#1)}
\newcommand\kc[1][usedefault, addprefix=\global, 1=3]{\ket[\hc[#1]]}

$$\kc[5]$$

\end{document}
```

The result I wanted is `|Hc(5)>`, but in fact it showed `|Hc(5>)`. Very weird.

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Apparently you're after some `bra` `ket` state vector notation?

Comment: Please don't use `$$...$$` as well, that's outdated -- Use `\[...\]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Christian. And yes, I was after the state vector notation. I wrote it in a simple way in the code just for convenience.

Comment: Is there some situation where you want LaTeX to typeset the text "usedefault, addprefix=\global, 1=1"? That's what happens if you do `\ket` with no argument. Why do you have this as an optional argument? (Why not just make it `\newcommand{\kc}[1]{\ket{\hx{#1}}}` and then `\[\k{5}\]`?)

Comment: @AndrewCashner: I suppose those options come from same package not used here

Comment: @andrew: Because in somewhere else in the main text I need to use \hc alone with a default value for the optional argument. The code above was extracted from a paper draft.

Comment: @QuantumPhysics: What package (not included in your minimal example) provides the options you specify in your macros?

Comment: @werner: I use LyX, and the code was generated automatically by LyX.

Comment: @QuantumPhysics: I wonder what happens with "`$$\kc$$`" only...

Comment: @QuantumPhysics: `LyX` is weird -- but I don't know why `LyX` is producing such options to your command sequences -- It requires a working keyvalue syntax/package that accepts those options ;-)

Comment: @Werner: I just tried that, and LaTex output an error.

Comment: @QuantumPhysics: Exactly. There is a package that is not being included in the code you display. Moreover, automated LyX export will put all preamble-related commands in the document preamble. I would suspect you've defined your `\newcommand`s inside Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble?

Comment: @christian@werner: LyX included the xargs package and used \newcommandx in the original code. The code I posted was simplified, but I left those options just because I did not know whether they were useful or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to group (well delimit rather) the inner command, that has an optional argument , with `{...}`, otherwise the whole command breaks apart and the contents of the arguments are typeset in the wrong order!

**Note**: There is a `braket` package for such Dirac/Hilbert state vectors.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\ket[1][usedefault, addprefix=\global, 1=1]{|#1\rangle}
\newcommand\hc[1][usedefault, addprefix=\global, 1=2]{Hc(#1)}
\newcommand\kc[1][usedefault, addprefix=\global, 1=3]{\ket[{\hc[#1]}]}

\[\kc[5]\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the `Hc` content should be in upright letters, but I leave this to the design/math content aficinados :-P

Comment: That works!! Thanks, Christian. By the way, I am curious how the LaTex executes the original code without {} to generate the weired result |Hc(5>)?

Comment: I cannot understand why '>' and ')' exchanges the order while they are originally in two different commands.

Comment: @QuantumPhysics: The reason is that in your version the `\@testopt` command (hidden internally) reads too far, beyond the delimiting inner `[...]` command, i.e. it reads the `>` first, assuming that this belongs to the content of the inner `[...]` pair. My version groups this inner command and forces LaTeX totreat this a whole argument (it's delimited), then expands the inner `\hc` command` and after that fetches the next token (the `>` character in this case)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, @ChristianHupfer. Does it mean that the \@testopt (or the \newcommand) does not work in the way like C, in which nested functions will be executed from inner to outer?

Comment: @QuantumPhysics: You should never compare TeX/LaTeX with a language like `C` -- Yes, it does not work like `C` . And please consider to accept my answer if the code is working then.